# Gitbook Code Block - Is it possible to display line numbers so, that it not always starts with number 1?

Tags: markdown, codeblocks, gitbook

I am planning to write a documentation with gitbook.com. I often have to insert and describe code. The code block is very good in gitbook.com. I found this in the documentation: https://docs.gitbook.com/editing-content/markdown#code-blocks. I can choose different languages and the syntax will be highlighted.

Now I explain many code blocks that are in one file. For example, I start a code block in my documentation with code that appears in my file on line 30.

Between the code blocks I insert my explanations.

Now I would like to change the line numbering in the code blocks in my documentation so that here is the line in the actual file. But: A code block starts in Gitbook always with the line number 1.

Maybe I'm missing something. Is it possible to specify in the code block which line number should be started?

Comment: I don't see support for _any_ line numbers in Gitbook's code blocks, even starting at 1.

Comment: You can see line numbers for example in the code blocks here: https://astridx.gitbook.io/leafletjs/eineschoenekarte